# Implemention of DDA algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, dda

I am trying to implement DDA algorithm in Java to draw a line. The Line Rasterizer implements an interface. Then I call the `rasterizeLine` function in class named `Canva`. The LineRasterizes successfully gets x and y points. No errors are thrown up, however there has to be some logical problem with the algorithm, because the line is not being drawed. Can you help me find the logical mistake?

**Interface**

```
    package rasterops;

import rasterdata.RasterImage;

public interface LineRasterizer<PixelType> {
    RasterImage<PixelType> rasterizeLine(RasterImage<PixelType> img,
                  double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2,
                  PixelType value);
}
```

**Line Rasterizer**

```
package rasterops;

import rasterdata.RasterImage;

public class LineRasterizerDDA<PixelType> implements LineRasterizer <PixelType> {
    @Override
    public RasterImage<PixelType> rasterizeLine(RasterImage<PixelType> img, double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, PixelType value) {


       double dy = y2-y1;
       double dx = x2-x1;

       double k = dy/dx;
       double y = y1;

        RasterImage<PixelType> result = img;
        for( double x = x1; x <= x2; x++ ){
            result = result.withPixel((int)x, (int)Math.round(y), value);
            y = y1 + k;
        }

        return result;



    }
}
```

**Canva - calling the function**

```
panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                previousX = e.getX();
                previousY = e.getY();
            }
        });
        panel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                final double startX = previousX / (panel.getWidth() - 1.0); //k zamysleni: proc 1.0 a ne 1?
                final double startY = 1 - previousY / (panel.getHeight() - 1.0);
                final double endX = e.getX() / (panel.getWidth() - 1.0);
                final double endY = 1 - e.getY() / (panel.getHeight() - 1.0);
                clear(); // zkuste zakomentovat
                rasterImage = liner.rasterizeLine(rasterImage,
                        startX, startY, endX, endY,
                        0xffff00);
                panel.repaint();
            }
        });
```

Comment: You [already asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920911/finding-a-bug-in-an-algorithm).

Comment: @AndyTurner I have deleted the first one.

Comment: Well, expect this one to be closed for the same reason and with similar comments. [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3788176)

Comment: @AndyTurner: OP has made several improvements in the posting; let's give this version a fair chance.  Among other things, he's worked around my general objections -- and I was the final "close" vote the first time.

Comment: @Prune the question is still "will you help me find the problem", which makes it off-topic.

Comment: @pajicekkralicek: what have you done to determine why nothing gets drawn?  Have you traced the execution flow to the point of the drawing command?  Have you checked the values of the drawing arguments?

Comment: @Prune seems like the values are computed as expected... Still got the feeling that I am missing some converts between the data types...

Comment: @pajicekkralicek [here is an MCVE](https://ideone.com/14U8ak) of your code, using a 2D boolean array instead of an image. It clearly doesn't work - but this is much better code to include in your question because it is simpler and self-contained.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
y = y1 + k;
```

keeps assigning the same value to `y`, because `y1` and `k` aren't changing.

[Example output, drawing line between (0,0) and (10, 10)](https://ideone.com/14U8ak):

```
O..........
.OOOOOOOOOO
...........
...........
...........
...........
...........
...........
...........
...........
...........
```

You may mean:

```
y = y + k;
```

or `y += k;`.

[Example output, drawing line between (0,0) and (10, 10)](https://ideone.com/Jx3DaO):

```
O..........
.O.........
..O........
...O.......
....O......
.....O.....
......O....
.......O...
........O..
.........O.
..........O
```

Comment: Nice save of a questionable question.  +1